# How can I efficiently concatenate multiple Arduino Strings?

Tags: c++, arduino

I was looking for an Arduino way of efficiently concatenating strings. I was looking for something like `std::format(" {} blah blah {}", str1, str2);`
I don't want to do something that will be slow such as

```
" " + str1 + " blah blah " + str2.
```

Comment: How do you know it's "slow"? How did you measure? Did you remember to enable optimizations when measuring? And what are your requirements?

Comment: @Alekk honestly it's not slow. Even Arduino's official documentation website gave a references about String addition as above. https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringAdditionOperator

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I was saying the + operation was slow because multiple strings are made in the process. For example: "blah" + " blah" +  " blah"; first makes a string containing "blah blah", then makes a string containing "blah blah blah". With more +s the more strings will be made. Im looking for something that combines them all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a concat function.

```
myString.concat(parameter);
```

You can use it as that. Reference: [Arduino Official Link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/concat/)

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently build a string, you can use `String.reserve()` and concatenate with the `+=` operator:

```
String string;
string.reserve(64);
string += " ";
string += str1;
string += " blah blah ";
string += str2;
```

This will only create one String object and doesn't reallocate the buffer all the time. It also works with numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, `sprintf`/`snprintf` with a stack buffer can be several times faster than using `String::operator+=`, even if you `reserve()` the appropriate amount first.

Being able to use these functions has a few prerequisites that make them not suitable for all use cases:

- You need to allocate the buffer, which means you need to know ahead of time a reasonable upper bound for the string length. In my case all of the variable parts were numbers, so I could pick extreme values and calculate how long they would make the string.
- You need to be able to use `char *` instead of `String`. This works for some functions, like `Serial.print`, but not everything.
- You can only format with primitive values: numbers, characters, and C strings. You can't use a class that provides a custom `operator String`.

As for which function to use: when in doubt, use `snprintf`. `sprintf` may be marginally faster but the difference isn't likely to be noticeable. On the other hand, if you under-allocated the buffer, `snprintf` will cut off the result string so it fits, while `sprintf` will overrun the buffer and potentially corrupt other data.